# HtDP2e Exercise 311: Average age in the family tree

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, binary-tree, racket, average

The exercise: Develop the function `average-age`. It consumes a family tree and the current year. It produces the average age of all `child` structures in the family tree.

Apparently this exercise is supposed to be solved in one function, however accumulators haven't been introduced yet so I'm wondering how can it be solved without using extra arguments representing intermediate result or creating helper functions.

Here is my solution:

```
(define CURRENT-YEAR 2020)

(define-struct no-parent [])
(define NP (make-no-parent))
(define-struct child [father mother name date eyes])
;; An FT (short for family tree) is one of:
;; - NP
;; - (make-child FT FT String Number String)
;; interp. a child in an ancestor family tree with father, mother, name, year of birth and color of eyes

;; Oldest generation:
(define Carl (make-child NP NP "Carl" 1926 "green"))
(define Bettina (make-child NP NP "Bettina" 1926 "green"))

;; Middle generation:
(define Adam (make-child Carl Bettina "Adam" 1950 "hazel"))
(define Dave (make-child Carl Bettina "Dave" 1955 "black"))
(define Eva (make-child Carl Bettina "Eva" 1965 "blue"))
(define Fred (make-child NP NP "Fred" 1966 "pink"))

;; Youngest generation:
(define Gustav (make-child Eva Fred "Gustav" 1988 "brown"))

;; Exercise 311
;; FT Number -> Number
;; Given ftree and current year, produce average age of all the child structures in the tree
;; ASSUME: the tree is not empty
(check-expect (average-age CURRENT-YEAR Carl)
              (/ (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Carl)) 1))
(check-expect (average-age CURRENT-YEAR Eva)
              (/ (+ (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Eva))
                                           (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Carl))
                                           (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Bettina)))
                                        3))
(check-expect (average-age CURRENT-YEAR Gustav)
              (/ (+ (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Gustav))
                    (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Eva))
                    (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Carl))
                    (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Bettina))
                    (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Fred)))
                 5))

;(define (average-age current-year ftree) 0)

(define (average-age current-year ftree)
  (mean (child-ages current-year ftree)))

;; ListOfNumber -> Number
;; calculates statistical mean for the given list of numbers, produces 0 for empty list
(check-expect (mean empty) 0)
(check-expect (mean (list 100 200 600)) 300)

;(define (mean lon) 0)

(define (mean lon)
  (cond [(empty? lon) 0]
        [else (/ (foldl + 0 lon)
                 (length lon))]))

;; Number FT -> Number
;; produces list of ages in the ftree by subtracting everyone's age from current year
(check-expect (child-ages CURRENT-YEAR Carl) (list (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Carl))))
(check-expect (child-ages CURRENT-YEAR Eva) (list (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Eva))
                                          (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Carl))
                                          (- CURRENT-YEAR (child-date Bettina))))

;(define (child-ages current-year ftree) empty)
(define (child-ages current-year ftree)
  (cond [(no-parent? ftree) empty]
        [else (cons (- current-year (child-date ftree))
                    (append (child-ages current-year (child-father ftree))
                            (child-ages current-year (child-mother ftree))))]))
```

Comment: I think you must be allowed to use `count-persons` from the previous exercise.  With this it is fairly easy.

Comment: Can you use `local`?

Comment: @atharva-shukla Chances are I can use `local` because it was introduced in the previous chapters, though it doesn't help to avoid creating helper functions.

Comment: @tfb the book doesn't force you what you are allowed to do and what you are not. I'm just wondering whether creating auxiliary functions is inevitable or I'm missing some possibility to do it in a single function.

Comment: a. multi-arguments can be emulated by consing the new arguments up into a new structure totally unexpected at "normal" invocation, and checking the structure of the received argument at each invocation, thus emulating, yes, a helper function; b. with explicit structural trees there's John McCarthy's tree-rotating [gopher](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+gopher) trick; but here the tree is implied, so you're back to the option a. it seems.

Comment: @will-ness to be honest I have no the slightest idea what all of that means, seems very far from the HtDP book in general and the given exercise in particular.

Comment: are you familiar with the car-cdr "cons trees" of Lisp?

Comment: @will-ness I'm familiar with first-rest `cons` in BSL, I guess it is the same conceptually.

Comment: then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62959036/849891) for a concrete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emulating the  [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) style, with reified explicit stack, emulating helper functions with specially-packaged arguments impossible at "normal" invocation,

```
(define (average-age node current-year)
   (cond
      ((pair? node)
          ;; helper function emulation
          .... )
      ((is-no-parent? node) (error "N/A"))
      ((is-child? node)
         (average-age       ; repackage for the helper, and start looping
              (list (list node)          ; emulated helper's 1st arg
                    (child-mother node)  ; emulated helper's rest of arguments
                    (child-father node))
              current-year))))
```

Perhaps you can see the solution from this? You don't even need to know what "CPS" means. Just follow the path; looping on each node's `mother` while putting the father aside for later processing, building up the list of nodes so that we can calculate this list's average age in the final step.

We use the list of *nodes seen so far,* so that we can check for duplicates while doing the "helper" loop processing, and *completely avoid processing any duplicates*.

This essentially is just a graph traversal. The *seen-so-far* nodes list is needed to skip the duplicates, avoid cycles, and also is used in the final processing step.

---

To add one more step at the solution composition,

```
(define (average-age node current-year)
   (cond
      ((pair? node)
          ;; helper function emulation
          ;; here we get the arguments as we've prepared them
          (let* ( (args        node)        ; it's not a _node_, here
                  (seen-so-far (car args)) 
                  (nodes       (cdr args)))
             (if (null? nodes)
                   ;; nothing more to do, return the result
               (the-result  seen-so-far)
                   ;; otherwise continue working
               (let ( (this-node  (car nodes))
                      (more-nodes (cdr nodes)))
                 (cond
                   ((or      ;; this-node is a dup, or none
                          (seen-before?  this-node  seen-so-far)
                          (is-no-parent? this-node))
                             ;; skip it
                      (average-age 
                          (cons  seen-so-far  more-nodes)
                          current-year))
                   ((is-child?  this-node)
                      ;; go on processing
                      (average-age 
                          (cons  seen-so-far     ; interim accumulator value
                            (cons  (child-mother this-node)   ; a TO_DO
                              (cons  (child-father this-node) ;  FIFO list
                                     more-nodes)))
                          current-year))
                   ....... )))))
    ..... ))
```

If I made a mistake here (and I did), correct it, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the HTDP languages well, or at all, so the code below is in fully-fledged Racket – sorry about this.

However one easy trick to solving this is to realise that the average age of a person is

- their age
- plus the sum of their parents' ages, each parent's age multiplied by how many people are in the parent's tree
- divided by the total number of people in *their* tree.

The function in the exercise just before this therefore helps a lot.

Note that this algorithm assumes the family tree is a tree.  In real life it is not: it's a DAG.

So here is a slightly different structure for people: people simply have a list of parents, which avoids a lot of annoying code and assumptions, together with two functions: `count-people` computes the number of people in the tree of a person, and `average-age` computes the average age of a person, given `count-people`.

```
(struct person
  (name
   born
   parents)
  #:transparent)

;;; This is just to make it easier to type in family trees
;;;
(define/match (desc->person desc)
  (((list* name born parents))
   (person name born (map desc->person parents))))

(define joe
  (desc->person '("joe" 2000
                        ("emily" 1975
                                 ("john" 1950)
                                 ("joan" 1950))
                        ("lucy" 1970
                                ("anne" 1945
                                        ("arabella" 1910))
                                ("erik" 1946)))))

(define (count-people p)
  (foldl + 1 (map count-people (person-parents p))))

(define (average-age when p)
  (/ (foldl + (- when (person-born p))
            (map (λ (pp)
                   (* (count-people pp)
                      (average-age when pp)))
                 (person-parents p)))
     (count-people p)))
```

It's fairly obvious that this calls `count-people` really a lot, and really repetitively, and a better definition would therefore memoize it:

```
(define count-people
  (let ([cache (make-weak-hasheqv)])
    (λ (p)
      (hash-ref! cache p
                 (thunk
                  (+ 1 (foldl + 0 (map count-people (person-parents p)))))))))
```

Of course, the count of people can be stored in the tree itself which means it is always immediate to compute:

```
(struct person
  (name
   born
   parents
   count)
  #:transparent)

(define (make-person name born parents)
  (person name born parents
          (+ 1 (for/sum ([p (in-list parents)])
                 (person-count p)))))

;;; This is just to make it easier to type in family trees
;;;
(define/match (desc->person desc)
  (((list* name born parents))
   (make-person name born (map desc->person parents))))

(define joe
  (desc->person '("joe" 2000
                        ("emily" 1975
                                 ("john" 1950)
                                 ("joan" 1950))
                        ("lucy" 1970
                                ("anne" 1945
                                        ("arabella" 1910))
                                ("erik" 1946)))))

(define (average-age when p)
  (/ (+ (- when (person-born p))
        (for/sum ([pp (in-list (person-parents p))])
          (* (person-count pp)
             (average-age when pp))))
     (person-count p)))
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the purpose of `count-people` when we can use `length` of people's ages list as I did in my solution.

Comment: @KonstantinKostanzhoglo: well, at least `length` is O(n) and requires building a large structure, but there's nothing wrong with it I suppose.  I think the idea of giving trees what are essentially weights (how many nodes in the tree) is quite generally useful however.

Comment: a side note re: your 2nd paragraph: too many pronouns, can't follow which is referring to what. a [matter of style](https://archive.org/stream/relativitythespe00einsuoft#page/n7/mode/2up/search/elegance). :)

Comment: however, if I'm guessing its meaning correctly, doesn't it *assume* no part of the tree of a person, above that person, is *shared*? surely this assumption is invalid, and it looks like invalid results are likely to be produced in such cases. consider a degenerate case of a diamond shaped tree. what is the bottom-most node's  weight? it's 1/4, not 1/5, isn't it.

Comment: @will-ness starting with a particular person, there can be only one pair of parents with siblings being skipped so there shouldn't be any duplicates.

Comment: A{father B, mother C}; B{father D, mother unknown}; C{father D, mother unknown}; D{father unknown, mother unknown} is a valid family tree structure, according to https://htdp.org/2018-01-06/Book/part_four.html. (well, I don't understand the "easy trick" mentioned in this answer, atm). there certainly is sharing in the book's example tree: Carl and Bettina; according to my current understanding they would be counted three times instead of one, with this "trick"; perhaps my current understanding is wrong.

Comment: @will-ness with B and C being parents of A and children of D means incest. Not sure the book encourages that :)

Comment: trees are abstract, "family" is just an example to make it easier to follow...

Comment: @will-ness Valid point, though I'm working with what is provided.

Comment: @will-ness by the way I suspect that the problem with avoiding counting the same node multiple times is resolved by adding accumulators which is introduced later in the book.

Comment: @WillNess: I have reworded the second paragraph, which was horrible: I hope it is less so now. (It is an endless irritation to me that there's no LaTeX in SE answers, so you have to write out maths in words.).  And yes, I'm assuming the tree is a tree and obviously in real life that's wrong: it's a DAG.  To process a DAG properly you need an occurs check I think, and the tree-weight trick fails miserably because the weight of a node is no longer 1 + the weight of its branches as there can be shared structure anywhere I think.  This example has quite badly damaged my opinion of HTDP, sadly.

Comment: @tfb Does it say anything bad about HtDP?

Comment: @KonstantinKostanzhoglo: What I meant is that I'd rather see them use an example where the real-world object they are modelling is a tree rather than teaching people, perhaps, to model things as trees which are not trees in real life(obviously you understand that it's just an exercise, but better for exercises to be right...)

Comment: re: LaTeX, you could compose an answer on math.SE,  save the rendered image, and  post that image here. :) :| :( :L :[ :/ :} :)